# What could be the cause of oscillating differential phase between a 2 channel audio signal

Tags: fft, audio, phase

## Test Setup

I have two i2s microphones (INMP441) on a common clock. They are designated as the left and right channels with a sampling rate of 22050Hz. The generated signals are stored as WAV files and are post processed using python. I am playing an audio tone of 5100Hz.

## Processing

The python processing slices the data into chunks of 1024 samples, windows them, takes the FFT and then computes the complex division between the two channels. I expect this to produce a constant differential phase.

## Output

But when I look at the output shown below, I do not see this.
[image: Signal Processing Output]

## Question

What could be the source of this oscillating phase?

Comment: It's because the phase is only unique to an additive factor of 360 degrees.  For this case you can just add 360 to the negative values.

Comment: use the scipy.signal.unwrap function first before subtracting.

Comment: Even if you discount the occasional 360 degree shift, the phase is still wandering around.  Assuming "perfect" sampling, a perfect source tone, and perfect processing, the phase shift should be around 20 degrees to account for the L/R delay.

Comment: Could you edit your question with a schematic, or schematic fragment, showing the connection of the two INMP441?  Perhaps also state your assumptions (see my answer, which I'll probably edit if you state _your_ assumptions in your question).

Comment: Also detail the serial clock rate and how you're sampling the left and right channels -- especially if you're controlling the L/R timing with software or hardware.

Comment: I would expect to see a pronounced tone in your FFT of the two channels -- are you sure your microphones are working right?  It might be a good idea to display a time-domain sample of the collected audio, in addition to the stuff you're showing there.

Comment: The time domain signals in that plot seem quite different to me. One does not look like a time shift of the other.